# Kivy Scater Transform doesn't work when in boxlayout

Tags: kivy

I'm trying to draw a mind map with kivy.

Starting with a scatter I can add nodes in a nest-able way that works fine. zooming and translating also work the way I want.

But then I try to add a button by putting my Scatter in a box layout the initializing translation no longer works. Se the code below.

When I use the small showapp (with only the treeWidget) like below the scatter initialises the way I want with the nodes in the center of the window, and plenty of space to add more nodes all around.

However when I change to the larger showapp (commented out) with the boxlayout the transform no longer works. The nodes are still there but they are of screen to the top right. You can make them visible by zooming out or panning in the right direction.

How to get this translation working again?

```py
### show-test04.py

import kivy 
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.graphics.transformation import Matrix
from kivy.uix.label import Label 
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput 
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget 
from kivy.core.window import Window


class NodeWidget(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, t, **kwargs):
        super(NodeWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation = 'horizontal'
        self.add_widget(TextInput(
            text = t,
            size_hint = (None, 1),
            height = 30,
            width = 250,
            multiline = False))
        self.box = BoxLayout(orientation = 'vertical')
        self.add_widget(self.box)

    def add_subWidget(self, widget):
        self.box.add_widget(widget)

# Creating Scatter Class 
class TreeWidget(Scatter):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TreeWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.size_hint=(None, None)
        self.size = 5000, 5000
        self.do_rotation=False

        self.rootpos = self.size[0]/2, self.size[1]/2
        mat = Matrix().translate(-self.rootpos[0] + Window.size[0]/2,
                                 -self.rootpos[1] + Window.size[1]/2, 0)
        self.apply_transform(mat)

        self.addRootNode('root', self.rootpos)
        self.addNode('beer')
        self.addNode('ginger')
        self.addNode('ale')

    def addRootNode(self, t, p):
        self.rootNode = NodeWidget(t)
        self.rootNode.pos = p
        self.add_widget(self.rootNode)

    def addNode(self, t):
        node = NodeWidget(t)
        self.rootNode.add_subWidget(node)

##class ShowApp(App): 
##    def build(self):
##        anchorTopLeft = AnchorLayout(anchor_x='left', anchor_y='top', padding=15)
##        buttonFile = Button(text='File', size_hint=(None, None), size=(60, 30))
##        anchorTopLeft.add_widget(buttonFile)
##        
##        treeWidget = TreeWidget()
##        mat = Matrix().translate(-treeWidget.rootpos[0] + Window.size[0]/2,
##                                 -treeWidget.rootpos[1] + Window.size[1]/2, 0)
##        treeWidget.apply_transform(mat)
##
##        boxLayout = BoxLayout()
##        boxLayout.add_widget(anchorTopLeft)
##        boxLayout.add_widget(treeWidget)
##        return boxLayout 

class ShowApp(App): 
    def build(self):
        return TreeWidget()

if __name__=='__main__':
    ShowApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure why but the solution below seems to work.

I've put the translation in a function of the App class, but after populating the scatter with some nodes by calling my buildTree function.:

```
class ShowApp(App): 
def build(self):
    self.treeWidget = TreeWidget()

    buttonFile = Button(text='File', size_hint=(None, None), size=(60, 30))
    buttonFile.bind(on_press=self.chooseFile)

    boxLayout = BoxLayout()
    boxLayout.add_widget(buttonFile)
    boxLayout.add_widget(self.treeWidget)
    return boxLayout

def chooseFile(self, obj):
    """ initialize the ElementTree object """
    self.tree = postree.posTree()
    self.buildTree()
    mat = Matrix().translate(-self.treeWidget.rootpos[0] + Window.size[0]/2,
                             -self.treeWidget.rootpos[1] + Window.size[1]/2, 0)
    self.treeWidget.apply_transform(mat)

def buildTree(self):
    for node in self.tree.rootNode.iter('node'):
        layout = self.tree.layout[node.attrib['ID']]
        self.treeWidget.addNode(node, layout)
```